# A special residually finite group

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Is there an example of a finitely generated (infinite) residually finite group $\Gamma$ for which every linear representation of $\Gamma$ has finite image?

Comment: By linear representation, do you mean *finite-dimensional* linear representation?

Comment: Yes, and over a field of characteristic zero.

Comment: I erased my answer, since it had the same properties as the Grigorchuk group (and is based on unpublished work), but I wanted to point out that Mark Sapir commented that the original construction of an infinite torsion residually finite group was due to Golod. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_group

Comment: @IanAgol: did you mean some Wilson's construction of just infinte groups of type N(h)? Is it published now?

Answer (score 16):

A group $G$ is **just infinite** if it is infinite but every proper quotient is finite.

Clearly a just infinite group which is not linear has the property that its image under any linear representation is finite.  Thus any group which is finitely generated, residually finite, not linear and just infinite is an example of what you want: for instance, the [Grigorchuk group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigorchuk_group).

Comment: That is, assuming the group itself isn't linear over a field of characteristic zero.  The Grigorchuk group works though as it is known not to be linear.

Comment: Note: I had a little trouble reading the answer (no doubt in large part because I am not a group theorist), so I decided to rewrite it.  I hope that is okay.  [P.S.: +1.]

Comment: These two references say that it is known that the Grigorchuk group is not linear.  http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2008/REUPapers/Waddle.pdf http://bernoulli.epfl.ch/graphs/talks/Buliga.pdf

Comment: It's not hard to prove that the Grigorchuk grp is not linear.  For instance, the Tits alternative says that every fg linear grp G either contains a solvable subgroup of finite index or contains a nonabelian free subgroup.  This implies that the "growth function" f(n) of G (here f(n) is the number of elements of G of length at most n in a fixed genset) grows either polynomially (if G has a solvable subgrp of finite index) or exponentially (if G contains a nonabelian free subgrp).  However, the first major thm about the Grigorchuk grp is that its growth fcn is superpolynomial but subexponential.

Comment: By the way, I highly recommend reading the final chapter in Pierre de la Harpe's book "Topics in Geometric Group Theory", which is entirely devoted to the Grigorchuk group.  It serves as a sort of "universal counterexample" to conjectures in geometric group theory.

Comment: @Andy: solvable groups can have exponential growth. For example ${\mathbb Z}\wr {\mathbb Z}$ is solvable of class 2 and has exponential growth because it contains a free non-cyclic subsemigroup.

Comment: @Pete, thanks for the far better rewriting of my answer.

Comment: Whoops!  Thanks for the correction Mark.  Is it true that any non-nilpotent solvable group has a free non-cyclic subsemigroup?

Comment: Andy - with a 'virtually' in front of 'nilpotent', that's the Milnor--Wolf Theorem.

Comment: @Andy: The fact that torsion linear groups are finite was known long before Tits-Milnor-Wolf. It is a theorem of Burnside (~1900). 